# Center image on page if tag is in an un-ordered list

Tags: html, css

I am trying to figure out how to center an image to the page instead of to the list item.

For example:

```
<div class="page">
  <!-- Margin could be anything -->
  <ul style="margin-left: 80px">
    <li>
      Some text. <!-- This could be really long -->
      <figure>
        <img class="image" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
        <figcaption>Image caption</figcaption> <!-- Needs to center to page not list item -->
      </figure>
    </li>
    <li>Other item</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

On a normal list, the list item will be indented a bit, which is what I want. However, I want the image to be centered to the page div not the list item. Is this possible? I would need it to work in IE 9 and preferably IE 8 as well.

Also, some of my lists may be indented a couple of levels to, so maybe `margin-left: 40px` or `margin-left: 80px` so I would need to account for this.

Here is a fiddle of a typical use case: https://jsfiddle.net/t4uoh7k7/

Comment: are the `<li>`'s the same width as the page `<div>`?

Comment: can you show us what the end result should look like? someone might be able to offer a better alternative than what you have

Comment: There's not enough info here to help you. Please show a more complete example, ideally in a code snippet or fiddle.

Comment: Centered both vertically and horizontally?

Comment: I added a fiddle of a typical use case, just needs the image centered with the page and not the list item. List items don't have any additional styling on them, just browser default. I am trying to center horizontally not vertically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use absolute positioning to do this, and it will center to the parenting relative object, which would hopefully be the page. I made a fiddle here:

https://jsfiddle.net/qgrb33sm/

```
.center-me-image{
position:absolute;
/*we have to spcify width to center*/
width:200px;
margin-left:-100px;
left:50%;
```

}

For this to work:
1. The page has to be the closest relative positioned parent
2. The width of the image has to be known.

item 2 can be achieved easily with javascript, and item 1 could be resolved by determining the offset of the parent with javascript as well.

Comment: The image needs to stay in it's spot though and not cover up any of the text. I the text is a few lines long or something, it will be covered up by the image. (It just needs the display: block property to fix this)

Comment: Easy enough to fix with JS, I updated your fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/t4uoh7k7/1/

Don't think you'll be able to do that with CSS alone.

Answer (score -2):

Is this what you are looking for.

```
<div class="page">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <p>Some text....</p>
            <img align="center" width="600" height="300" src="/some/image.png" hspace="25" vspace="25"/>
        </li>
    </ul>

</div>
```